# C++ Hashmap Key value Pair is wiped after calling function a second time

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

I am using a hashmap to store roman numeral key value pairs, but it seems that it stores it initially during the first function call but when the function is called with another expression the key value pair previously stored does not exist. I thought passing by reference would keep the values constant throughout but that does not seem to be the case, any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
void convertToPostFixAndPrint(const std::vector<Token *> &assignmentStatement, std::map<char, int> &symTable) {
    InfixToPostfix *itop = new InfixToPostfix();
    std::vector<Token *> postfixTokens;
    std::vector<Token *> tokens;
    // The convert function expects an infix expression, not
    // an assignment statements. Therefore, we store the
    // tokens that represent the expression in "tokens"
    // and use it to convert the infix expression.
    for (int i = 2; i < assignmentStatement.size(); i++)
        tokens.push_back(assignmentStatement.at(i));
    itop->convert(tokens, postfixTokens);
    std::cout << "\nThe postfix expression has " << postfixTokens.size() << " tokens.\n";
    for (auto postfixToken: postfixTokens)
        postfixToken->print();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Debugging statements
    std::cout << "Test: " << assignmentStatement[0]->variable() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Test: " << assignmentStatement[2]->romanNumber() << std::endl;
//    RomanNumeral * roman = new RomanNumeral(postfixTokens[0]->romanNumber());
//    std::cout << "Test Int: " << roman->convertRomanToInt() << std::endl;
    romanCalc(postfixTokens, tokens, symTable);

}


void romanCalc(const std::vector<Token *> &postfixVector, const 
 std::vector<Token *> &infixVector, std::map<char, int> &symTable) {
    // If letter does not exist in map, we append it
    if(symTable.find(infixVector[0]->variable()) == symTable.end()){
        symTable[infixVector[0]->variable()];
    }

    std::stack<int> romanStack;


    for(auto roman: postfixVector) {
        // Fetches roman numeral using roman class
        RomanNumeral * romans = new RomanNumeral(roman->romanNumber());

        if(romans->isValidRomanNumeral()) {
            // Pushes decimal value of Roman onto stack
            romanStack.push(romans->convertRomanToInt());
        }

        // If we read a letter, we retrieve the letter from the map and push it onto stack
        else if(roman->isAVariable()) {
            std::cout << "Variable: " << roman->variable() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Value retrieved from " << roman->variable() << " is " << symTable[roman->variable()] << std::endl;
            if(symTable.find(roman->variable()) != symTable.end()){
                romanStack.push(symTable[roman->variable()]);
            }

            // Used for debugging
//            for(int i = 0; i < romanStack.size(); i++) {
//                std::cout << "Printing Stack: " << romanStack.top() << std::endl;
//                romanStack.pop();
//            }
        }

        // Once we got the decimals
        else {
            // Storing prev two numbers into ints and popping them from numbers vector
            int second = romanStack.top();
            romanStack.pop();
            std::cout << second << " second\n";

            int first = romanStack.top();
            romanStack.pop();
            std::cout << first << " first\n";

            if(roman->isAdditionOperator())
                romanStack.push(first + second);
            else if(roman->isSubtractionOperator())
                romanStack.push(first - second);
            else if(roman->isMultiplicationOperator())
                romanStack.push(first * second);
            else if(roman->isDivisionOperator())
                romanStack.push(first / second);
            else if(roman->isModuloOperator())
                romanStack.push(first % second);
            else {
                std::cout << "Expected an arithmetic operator instead found the following token \n";
                roman->print();
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    // Store top val of stack (Calculated Decimal) onto specified letter
    symTable[infixVector[0]->variable()] = romanStack.top();

    std::cout << "Testing Retrieve from map: " << symTable[infixVector[0]->variable()] << std::endl;

    // return decimal conversion
    std::cout << romanStack.top() << std::endl;
}

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

     // Pass as reference to other functions
     std::map<char, int> symTable;

    // create a tree and then print the values of its nodes
    // from the smallest to the largest.
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " nameOfAnInputFile\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    std::fstream inputStream;
    inputStream.open(argv[1], std::ios::in);
    if (!inputStream.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open " << argv[1] << ". Terminating...";
        exit(1);
    }


    Tokenizer tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputStream);
    std::vector<Token *> assignmentStatement;
    Token *token = tokenizer.getToken();


    // The assumption is that there is at least one new-line character
    // to terminate the last statement before end-of-file gets detected.
    while( ! token->eof() ) {
        // Pushes all tokens into vector
        assignmentStatement.push_back(token);
        // If we hit an end of line "\n" we then use our token filled vector do stuff
        if(token->eol()) {
            convertToPostFixAndPrint(assignmentStatement, symTable);
            assignmentStatement.clear();
        }
        token->print();
        token = tokenizer.getToken();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Here is my debug output which shows that b does not contain a value after the second function call,

```
 b  =  XII
The postfix expression has 1 tokens.
 XII
Test: b
Test: XII
Testing Retrieve from map: 12
12
EOL c  =  MMDCCCLXXXVIII  +  b
The postfix expression has 3 tokens.
 MMDCCCLXXXVIII  b  +
Test: c
Test: MMDCCCLXXXVIII
Variable: b
Value retrieved from b is 0
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your example until only the described problems occur.

Comment: It occurs in the first function posted but just wanted to show the main function and how the map and such function with each other.

Comment: Please provide some examples of real (wrong) input/output and expected input/output. What did you find when debugging the program?

Comment: I updated my post with the debug output :)

Comment: @Debug, it's still difficult to see where exactly to look for mistakes. I assume you are talking about the `romanCalc` function, but I can't even see if this function is called in your code. You need to write the question in a QA ticket manner, like: if I call this function with parameter A I expect it to produce output C, but it gives me output B. Why not C?

Comment: Its called within another function let me update it real quick

Comment: Its updated @TheDreamsWind

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk

Comment: it also may be issue with Tokenizer because its design looks peculiar. Where tokens are stored? How they get deallocated? It's not clear and design cast suspicion on that storage used is temporary. By look of it it's not complete code but also it's too much of code. You have to break program so you can test each module if it works right.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Tokens gets stored in a vector and gets cleared each time it hits an end of line

Comment: @Debug they aren't. pointers to them are, that's why it's an instant suspect :P

Comment: You should post a [mcve].